# Create a script to store a number of colors so gameObject is selected menu will display colors and user selects one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ultimately this will be used with VR and I know I'll need some sort of menu when it comes to this but right now I'm looking to write the script for just changing the color of then objects in the game. How can I store the colors that I want and when the user clicks on a certain object, the color will change? Right now I'm looking at this below as an example, so when the user clicks on the object it'll change with whatever materials are stored. What I want is to implement this for VR and how I should go on about that.

```
public class ColorChanging : MonoBehaviour {

public Material[] materials;//Allows input of material colors in a set size of array;
public Renderer Rend; // what's being rendered

private int index = 1;//Initialize at 1

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Rend = GetComponent<Renderer> ();//Gives functionality for the renderer
    Rend.enabled = true;//Makes the rendered 3d object visable if enabled;
}

void OnMouseDown() {

    if (materials.Length == 0)//If there are no materials nothing happens.
        return;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        index += 1;//When mouse is pressed down we increment up to the next index location

    if (index == materials.Length + 1)//When it reaches the end of the materials it starts over.
        index = 1;

    print (index);

    Rend.sharedMaterial = materials [index - 1]; 

    }
}
```

}

Comment: So what is your problem? What is not working?   Btw the checks like "if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))" are usually done in update, not in OnMouseDown cause OnMouseDown is an event fired when mouse button is pressed, so that's kind of useless double checking

Comment: The script works, just the problem is I wanted to create a script where it would store a number of colors and use a boolean. But thank you I'll move it to update.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to change the color, then you can only manipulate color instead of materials.

```
public class ColorChanging : MonoBehaviour {

public Color[] colors; // To be set from Unity editor
public Renderer Rend;  // what's being rendered

private int currentIndex = 0;

void Start ()
{
    Rend = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
    Rend.enabled = true;
    if (colors.Length > currentIndex)
        Rend.sharedMaterial.color = colors[currentIndex];
}

// Use update instead of OnMouseDown
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        if (materials.Length > currentIndex)
            return;
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.Length;
        Rend.sharedMaterial = materials [index - 1]; 
    }
}
```

if you don't want to do this in Update, you can keep doing it in OnMouseDown but remove the Input check :

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (materials.Length > currentIndex)
        return;
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % colors.Length;
    Rend.sharedMaterial = materials [index - 1]; 
}
```

Note that your 3D objects needs to have a collider component to trigger this events and the scene needs to have an Event System (the thing automatically created when you put UI elements in a scene).